# Disaster recovery for Web Services

Tags: web-services, architecture, scheduled-tasks

I had form a system integration between system A and system B. System A would sync a same record to system B everytime a new record was inserted into a local Database of system A via Web Services. When there is some exception or failure to cause the web services disconnected, system A does not able to sync record to system B because the web services to be consume from system B cannot be reach. Is there any best practice to cater scenario in real life like this ? The new record created in system A cannot duplicate to system B. What if I schedule a job to check any failure record sync to system B and once the web services was back to online and trigger a patching operation to patch the record in system A back to system B?

Answer (score 0):

You have answer in your query. You can maintain a flag in System As rows, whether the Sync happened successfully or not (one more column with values true for successful sync and false (default value)  failed sync). During happy scenario once the sync happened successfully your webservice can return success with insertion and you can mark the flag true in source system. If there are issues during sync your source rows will have default value which false. You can have failover webservice which can look for rows with false status and sync again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other best solution or more practical workaround to solve this issues. Especially when it comes to an Enterprise level application, what is the most conventional way to cater it ? For me it is a bit slow and unpractical.